# Call order of performActionForShortcutItem vs applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

So, i have an app that has server state, and i refresh it by a timeout value and checking that timeout in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, reloading if timeout has expired.
This has worked well up until now.

I now want to implement new force touch shortcut action that performs a server operation. However, i don’t want the status-fetch operation to happen at the same time as the shortcut action. This is not a problem when the app is launched through a shortcut, but when transitioning from inactive -> active, i could end up starting one server operation in the `applicationWillEnterForeground`, and another in `performActionForShortcutItem`, which is not optimal.

What i'm after is to only potentially refresh my state if the app is *not* (re)launched as a result of a force touch press.

I thought i would solve this by a bool, “isHandlingShortcut” that i set in `performActionForShortcutItem` and then check in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, and in that case skip my refresh - but turns out it doesn’t work since `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called first!

Is there *any* way i can find out that i’ve (re)launched the app via a shortcut in `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

EDIT: perhaps i could move my "refresh"-logic to `applicationDidBecomeActive`? That one is called after `performActionForShortcutItem`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> [...] check, on launch, whether your app is being launched via a quick
>   action. Perform this check in your
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method by checking for the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey launch option key. The
>   UIApplicationShortcutItem object is available as the value of the
>   launch option key.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622935-application

What I'm doing is checking the shortcut that comes in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` so later in `performActionForShortcutItem` I know whether the app was launched due to the shortcut or the app was already launched.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (executed if shourtcut launches the app):

```
self.launchShortcutItem = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey];
```

And later in `performActionForShortcutItem`:

```
if (self.launchShortcutItem) {
    // app launched due to shortcut
} else {
    // app was already launched
}
```